# jConnect4 pooled connection does not work as documented

Tags: jdbc, sybase, jconnect

[Official Sybase jConnect Programmers Reference](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.../prjdbc0700.pdfSimilarShare) suggests following way to use pooled connections:

```
SybConnectionPoolDataSource connectionPoolDataSource = new SybConnectionPoolDataSource();
...
Connection ds = connectionPoolDataSource.getConnection();
...
ds.close();
```

However getDataSource always causes exception. I decompiled SybConnectionPoolDataSource and found that the method call explicitly generates an error:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    ErrorMessage.raiseError("JZ0S3", "getConnection()");
    return null;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the documentation contradicts to the implementation?

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment specifically for Sybase because 1) I don't use it and 2) your link doesn't work, but I can try to give you a theory based on my own experience maintaining a JDBC driver (Jaybird/Firebird JDBC) and looking at what some of the other implementations do.

The [`ConnectionPoolDataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html) is probably the least understood part of the JDBC API. Contrary to what the naming suggests and how it has been implemented in some JDBC implementations this interface **SHOULD NOT** provide connection pooling and should not implement `DataSource` (or at least: doing that can lead to confusion and bugs; *my own experience*).

The javadoc of the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not very helpful, the [`javax.sql`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html) package documentation provides a little bit more info, but you really need to look at the JDBC 4.1 specification, Chapter 11 *Connection Pooling* to get a good idea how it should work:

> [...] the JDBC driver provides an implementation of `ConnectionPoolDataSource` that the application server uses to build and manage the connection pool.

In other words: `ConnectionPoolDataSource` isn't meant for direct use by a developer, but instead is used by an application server for its connection pool; it isn't a connection pool itself.

> The application server provides its clients with an implementation of the `DataSource` interface that makes connection pooling transparent to the client.

So the connection pool is made available to the user by means of a normal `DataSource` implementation. The user uses this as would it be one that doesn't provide pooling, and uses the connections obtained as if it is a normal physical connection instead of one obtained from a connection pool:

> When an application is finished using a connection, it closes the logical connection using the method `Connection.close`. This closes the logical connection but does not close the physical connection. Instead, the physical connection is returned to the pool so that it can be reused.
>
> Connection pooling is completely transparent to the client: A client obtains a pooled connection and uses it just the same way it obtains and uses a non pooled connection.

This is further supported by the documentation of [`PooledConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/PooledConnection.html) (the object created by a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`):

> An application programmer does not use the `PooledConnection` interface directly; rather, it is used by a middle tier infrastructure that manages the pooling of connections.
>
> When an application calls the method `DataSource.getConnection`, it gets back a `Connection` object. If connection pooling is being done, that `Connection` object is actually a handle to a `PooledConnection` object, which is a physical connection.
>
> The connection pool manager, typically the application server, maintains a pool of `PooledConnection` objects. If there is a `PooledConnection` object available in the pool, the connection pool manager returns a `Connection` object that is a handle to that physical connection. If no `PooledConnection` object is available, the connection pool manager calls the `ConnectionPoolDataSource` method `getPoolConnection` to create a new physical connection. The JDBC driver implementing `ConnectionPoolDataSource` creates a new `PooledConnection` object and returns a handle to it.

Unfortunately, some of JDBC drivers have created data sources that provide connection pooling by implementing both `DataSource` and `ConnectionPoolDataSource` in a single class, instead of the intent of the JDBC spec of having a `DataSource` that **uses** a `ConnectionPoolDataSource`. This has resulted in implementations that would work if used as a normal `DataSource`, but would break if used as a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (eg in the connection pool of an application server), or where the interface was misunderstood and the wrong methods where used to create connections (eg calling `getPooledConnection().getConnection()`).

I have seen implementations (including in Jaybird) where the `getPooledConnection()` would be used to access a connection pool internal to the implementation, or where only connections obtained from the `getConnection()` of the implementation would work correctly, leading to all kinds of oddities and incorrect behavior when that implementation was used to fill a connection pool in an application server using the `getPooledConnection()`.

Maybe Sybase did something similar, and then decided that wasn't such a good idea so they changed the `DataSource.getConnection()` to throw an exception to make sure it wasn't used in this way, but at the same time maintaining the API compatibility by not removing the methods defined by `DataSource`. Or maybe they extended a normal `DataSource` to easily create the physical connection (instead of wrapping a normal one), but don't want users to use it as a `DataSource`.